Error crítico al usar Google Maps y polilíneas en Flutter: polilíneas desaparecen o no se muestran correctamente
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Flutter que utiliza Google Maps para mostrar rutas mediante polilíneas. Sin embargo, me encuentro con un problema serio: las polilíneas a veces no se renderizan correctamente, desaparecen después de dibujarlas, o no aparecen en absoluto. Esto sucede incluso cuando la consola no muestra errores específicos. He intentado varias soluciones sin éxito.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';


class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController? _controller;
  Set<Polyline> _polylines = {};

  final LatLng _start = LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194); // San Francisco
  final LatLng _end = LatLng(34.0522, -118.2437); // Los Ángeles

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setPolylines();
  }

  void _setPolylines() {
    _polylines.add(
      Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId("route"),
        points: [_start, _end],
        width: 5,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Google Maps Error")),
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _start, zoom: 7),
        polylines: _polylines,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Que errores se muestran en la consola?

Comentas que en ocasiones si se muestran pero desaparecen, en este caso te sugiero que en _setPolylines() haz uso de setState() :
void _setPolylines() {
  setState(() {
    _polylines.add(
      Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId("route"),
        points: [_start, _end],
        width: 5,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  });
}


setState()  Al llamar a setState, se notifica al marco que el estado interno de este objeto ha cambiado de una manera que podría
afectar la interfaz de usuario en este subárbol, lo que hace que el
marco programe una compilación para este objeto State.
Si simplemente cambia el estado directamente sin llamar a setState, el
marco podría no programar una compilación y la interfaz de usuario
para este subárbol podría no actualizarse para reflejar el nuevo
estado.
Generalmente, se recomienda que el método setState solo se use para
encapsular los cambios reales en el estado, no cualquier cálculo que
pueda estar asociado con el cambio. Por ejemplo, aquí se incrementa un
valor usado por la función de compilación y luego el cambio se escribe
en el disco, pero solo el incremento se encapsula en setState:

